# memcpy and memset function to java

Tags: java, c, memcpy

I am currently adapting a DLL written in C to Java and I am having problems with the memcpy and memset C functions.

Here is what I want to convert (it's not the whole code) :

```
    int res = 0;
    int bytes_written = 0;
    int totalsize;
    int reportid;
    hid_device *handle;
    unsigned char trans_data[64];
    unsigned char *buf;

    buf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, NULL);


    memcpy(trans_data+2,buf+bytes_written+2,totalsize);
    memset(trans_data+2+totalsize,0,64-(totalsize+2));
```

For memcpy, I know there's System.arraycopy but when using it the following way, it's not what I expect

```
        System.arraycopy(trans_data, 2, buff, 2, totalsize);
```

Comment: It seems you're going to meet with sun.misc.Unsafe :)

Comment: But maybe a first thing would be to ask yourself - do you really need it implemented this way? Maybe the Java way can solve it better?

Comment: for just padding zeros to a byte array ? :p

Comment: I have written 90% of the DLL functions, what this function does is just splitting an array of 250 byte to 64 ones, but the last array has to be padded with zeros.

Comment: It is generally a really bad idea to translate code. Consider extracting the logic and re-implementing the $target-way instead.

Comment: @Romain: For such a simple task, it might be easier to just reimplement that function from scratch, rather than trying to port from C. You'll probably arrive at a similar solution to the C function, you'll be able to reason about it more easily while writing.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `arraycopy`? It looks like you have the source and destination reversed. *"it's not what I expect"* It would be helpful if you told us what you expect and what happens so we don't have to make assumptions.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, I read the doc for arraycopy, I've just written the code, not copy paste from my project.. What I expect is, as I said in a previous comment, that the last array split which lengths is not equal to 64byte is padded with zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take into account that the order of destination/source parameters is different in C memcpy and Java arraycopy

C's `memcpy(b+2, a+1, 2);` is equivalent to Java's `System.arraycopy(a, 1, b, 2, 2);` and it means "copy positions 1 and 2 from array a into positions 2 and 3 of array b".

Try reordering your parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I did ^^ What about the memset ? That's my main problem

Comment: You can use [fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20byte)) method `fill(byte[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, byte val)`
Assigns the specified byte value to each element of the specified range of the specified array of bytes.